# How to recover a database in SQL

Tags: database, sql

I have a *.mdf and *.ndf files but *.log is missing. Is it possible to recover the database?

Comment: Try this on ServerFault.

Comment: Why it is programming related as well as this can be done using valid T-SQL.  I don't think the server fault folks know that much TSQL.

Comment: Are we to guess that you're talking about Microsoft SQL Server? Please be specific. SQL is a language, not a system.

Answer (score 4):

Look up sp_attach_single_file_db in BOL.

Also you can use:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname ON <file> [,...n] FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
```

Answer (score 1):

With some third party tools you can.  We used Lumigent Log Explorer, which is no longer available.  However, if you do a Google (or Bing) search, you will come up with all sorts of alternatives to Log Explorer.

However, your question will get a better answer on serverfault.com

Comment: I think he will get a better answer on here as it is TSQL related. Serverfault may help if he is looking for a backup but he doesn't have a backup.

Comment: @JonH We here on ServerFault know as much or more about administrative T-SQL as the folks at StackOverflow (where many of us also post).